# dynamic stylesheets in om

Tags: css, clojurescript, om

I have an ClojureScript Om app with different pages which are actually just different components in the same app, each page can have some different components that have different stylesheets.  Some of these stylesheets are quite complex and can override each other.  Is there a way in Om to disable/enable stylesheets, or load them inside a component, rather than having them at the top level where I will have to spend a lot of time changing them to make sure they don't conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Om doesn't help you with CSS. If you are talking about inline styles as proposed [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) there is nothing you preventing you from declaring your CSS as js objects and passing them to om components.

Also, look at [radium](http://projects.formidablelabs.com/radium/), you might want to integrate it with om.

Comment: OK thanks, I think I should really just consolidate my stylesheets, it looks like inline styles would make things a bit messy in my case, even with a nice library like this.